# Can you save a SAS program inside a process flow on SAS Web/Studio through code?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Is there a way to run your code and have a line at the end that saves the program you just ran?

Me and my team use SAS Studio/Web process flow. Since programs inside SAS Studio process flow aren't related to programs outside the process flow, we are interested in a way to save each program after it's ran on a folder outside the process flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a way to solve this using %include.

With %include "SAS program address"; you can run a specific SAS program outside your process flow. Now, instead of having the code on our process flow, we will have only the %include line on each program.